# Keep Search Parameters Through Pagination

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

Somewhat new to Laravel(4.2) and I'm having issues with pagination on my search function. So far I've been able to successfully carry out a search, though in the rare cases it actually goes over onto a second page it resets to simply "?page=2"

Below is the code for the form.

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'post', 'name' => 'all', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate')) }}
                          <input type="text" name="srch_lname" class="input-large" value="{{ Input::old('srch_lname', Session::get('srch_lname')) }}" />

                          <input type="text" name="srch_fname" class="input-large" value="{{ Input::old('srch_fname', Session::get('srch_fname')) }}" />
.
.
.
<?php echo $employees->links(); ?>
```

And the controller handling the search.

```
public function getIndex() {

        $srch_lname = Session::get('srch_lname');
        $srch_fname = Session::get('srch_fname');

        $employees = vEmployees::co()->restrictions()
            ->where('lastname', 'LIKE', $srch_lname . '%')
            ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $srch_fname . '%')
            ->orderBy('lastname')
            ->orderBy('firstname')
            ->paginate(10);

        return View::make('index')
            ->with('employees', $employees)
            ->with('title', 'Users')
            ->with('pagetitle', 'Employees')
            ->with('pagedescription', '')
    }


    public function postIndex() {

        if (Input::has('btnSearch')) {

            return Redirect::to('/employees')->with('search', 1)
                ->with('srch_lname', Input::get('srch_lname'))
                ->with('srch_fname', Input::get('srch_fname'))
```

I've been trying some other solutions found throughout SO though it either ends up causing issues or bringing me back to the same problem.

Any sort of push in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append the search data to the pagination `links()`

```
<?php echo $employees->appends(array("srch_lname" => ...))->links(); ?>
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links

Comment: I added the appends and it does show that in the URL when the user moves to the next page, though it doesn't actually carry the search over onto the next page it just resets the table even with the URL appended.


`<?php echo $employees->appends(array("srch_lname" => Input::get('srch_lname'), "srch_fname" => Input::get('srch_fname') ))->links(); ?>`

There's my appends

Comment: @Josh try changing `Input::get` to `Session::get`.

Comment: I changed it to Session::get and it's still giving me the same issue.(Keeping Values in appends but not actually carrying the search over to page 2)

So could it be an issue with the form's values itself not carrying over since the appends is now working?